# Create a thread in custom view will be leak memory?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, java-threads

```
public class CustomView extends View{
   public CustomView (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
  public CustomView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                   //dosomething; 
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

When the screen config change or other things , it will be leak memory?
If it will be , how should I do ?  Thanks.

Comment: when activity destroy ,you need stop thread,or use WeakReference<context> ...

Answer (score 1):

> When the screen config change or other things , it will be leak
>   memory?

it will, because of the infinite loop.

> how should I do

you have to force your thread to terminate is run method. You could, for instance, setting a `boolean` that is going be evaluated in the while, and force this `boolean` `onDetachedFromWindow`